# Black and Scholes equation for portfolio **with** arbitrage

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

I am well aware of how the ordinary Black and Scholes equation is derived, under the assumption of an arbitrage free portfolio, $V=G-hS$. Here $S$ is the price of the underlying and $G$ is the option price. Suppose now that the portfolio is stochastic, and follows the process
$$(1): dV=rVdt+f(V,t)VdW,$$
where $r$ is a constant parameter. The change of the portfolio also satisfies $dV=dG-h \cdot dS$. In the standard Black and Scholes, we have $h = \partial G/\partial S$. Assuming that the underlying follows a GBM, we have
$$dS = \mu S dt + \sigma SdW,$$
where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constant parameters. Itô's lemma then provides
$$dG = \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}+\mu S\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial G^2}{\partial S^2} \right)dt + \sigma S\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}dW,$$
so that
$$(2): dV=dG-hdS = \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}+\mu S\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}-h\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial G^2}{\partial S^2} \right)dt + \sigma S\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}-h\right)dW $$

Matching 1) and 2), we see that we must have the following implicit relation for $h$ $$(3): f(G-hS,t)(G-hS)=\sigma S \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}-h\right). $$
In the standard Black and Scholes we would have $f=0$, thus recovering $h = \frac{\partial G}{\partial S}$. If $f$ only depends on its second argument ($t$), then 3) can also easily be solved for $h$, yielding $$(5):h =\frac{Gf(t)-\sigma S \frac{\partial G}{\partial S}}{S(f(t)-\sigma)}, \ f \ \mathrm{independent \ of} \ V$$

Combining 1) and 2) would then give the Black and Scholes like equation $$(6):\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}+\mu S\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial G^2}{\partial S^2}+(r-\mu)\frac{Gf(t)-\sigma S \frac{\partial G}{\partial S}}{f(t)-\sigma}-rG=0, \ f \ \mathrm{independent \ of} \ V  $$

**EDIT**

The above model is considered in the following paper by [Contreras et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437110003572). They write the stochastic portfolio 1) as $$(1'): dV=rVdt+f(t,S(t))VdW. $$ Then $h$ can again be determine as in equation 5), yielding the Black and Scholes like equation 6). See section 2 of the cited paper.

However, I would like to know what could we do if $f$ is *not* independent of $V$, i.e. if we retain the formulation in 1).

**EDIT**

I edit the question to clarify what I mean. Suppose we retain the dependence of $V$ in $f$. With $V=G-hS$, we can write equation 3) as
$$(7):f(V,t)-\sigma V = \sigma S \frac{\partial G}{\partial S} - \sigma G.$$
Suppose the function $V \mapsto f(V,t)V-\sigma V$ is invertible for each $t$ and $\sigma$, and call the inverse $\phi$, so that $\phi(x,t) = (V \mapsto f(V,t)V-\sigma V)^{-1}(x)$. We can then solve for $h$ to get
$$(8):h=\frac{G-\phi(\sigma S \frac{\partial G}{\partial S} - \sigma G,t)}{S},$$
from which we get the modified Black and Scholes equation 
$$(9): \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}+\mu S\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial G^2}{\partial S^2}+(r-\mu)\left[G-\phi(\sigma S \frac{\partial G}{\partial S} - \sigma G,t) \right]-rG=0.$$
If $f$ is independent of $V$ then $\phi(x,t) = x/(f(t)-\sigma)$, so we recover the previous equation 6).

However, for a general function $f$ the map $V \mapsto f(V,t)V-\sigma V$ is *not* invertible. Consider, for example, $f(V,t)=V$, for which $V \mapsto f(V,t)V-\sigma V = V^2 - \sigma V$ is not invertible. Then we cannot uniquely determine $h$. Can we say anything about the equation for $G$ in this case?

Comment: Just two notes.  First, it is a necessary assumption of Ito calculus that all parameters are known by all actors with perfect knowledge.  Second, independence is a conclusion.  You cannot arrive anywhere else under these assumptions.  If all parameters are known, then how do you get arbitrage to arise?  When you drop the assumption of perfect knowledge, none of these equations fall out of the math.  Perfect knowledge is an enormous amount of information in this case.  I will give you a hint, however, instead of assuming an absence of arbitrage, assume de Finetti's coherence principle holds.

Comment: @DaveHarris I'm afraid I don't quite understand your objections. The model is an attempt to describe a market where arbitrage opportunities may arise. However, this is not my field of expertise, so you may be right. The model where $f$ does not depend explicitly on $V$ is discussed here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437110003572. See in particular section 2. I will add this link to my question also.

Comment: Are you a mathematics or an econ student?  Also, are you a grad student?  The answers would be very different if your concern is as a mathematical object as opposed to being a tool.

Comment: @DaveHarris I study mathematics and physics. I am not a grad student. The question comes from a question, that I didn't fully solve, on a past exam in basic econophysics. I could work it out (as done above) for $f$ independent of $V$, but not in the case of $f$ dependent on $V$.